# Refresh folder dynamically at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

How can I refresh project folder dynamically at runtime using java program. Actually I created the java file dynamically and I have read the created java file at the same time. But it shows class not found exception. when I refresh the project folder once, its working properly. Is there is any way to refresh folder dynamically . I have tried

- eclipse **-->** window **-->** preferences **-->** general **-->** workspace

  and enable Refresh automatically. but I need it dynamically.Kindly help me .

Comment: Your program is creating a `.java` file in an Eclipse workspace, and you want Eclipse to immediately notice and compile it so your program can load the compiled class?  That seems like a bad idea.  Consider using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` to make your program compile the generated `.java` file itself.

Comment: Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) is supposed to ***finally*** fix auto-refresh in Java. You might want to download and try it out - might be the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a program that does similar. I would suggest possibly checking to see if it exists and/or creating a new File object to correspond to the file you added.